# vertical spaces after equation

Tags: spacing, equations

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage\[hmarginratio=2:2\]{geometry}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{ upgreek }
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
The survival function is defined as the probability that an individual survives longer than t. It can be expressed as\\
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\begin{align*}
S(t)&=P(T>t)\\
&=1-P(T\leq t)\\
&=1-F(t)
\end{align*}\\

    The survival function of the Gompertz distribution is given by,
    \begin{equation}
    S(t;\gamma;\lambda)=\text{exp}\left\[\frac{\lambda}{\gamma}(1-e^{\gamma t})\right\]
    \end{equation}\\
    The hazard function of survival time is defined as the probability that an individual fails in a very short interval, t + $\Delta$t, given that the individual has survived to t.
    \begin{equation}
    \frac{\lim_{\Delta t\to 0} P\left\[
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    an individual fails in the interval $(t, t+\Delta t)$,\\
    given the individual has survived to t
    \end{tabular}
    \right\]}
    {\Delta t}
    \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

[image: can i apply the abovedisplayskip and belowdisplayskip to only one equation? i just want to use it for the equation with "allign"]

Can I apply the `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` to only one equation? I just want to use it for the equation with `align` but it applies for every equation below it.

Comment: is `\\ ` after `align` intentional?  remove them and **not** change deliberately defined `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` amounts.

Comment: You are apparently using `\onehalfspacing` or `\doublespacing` for producing the image, but don't set them in the example.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

in your document you have many issues, so i doubt that you can compile it:

- `\left\[` is wrong, correct is `\left[` also similarly for `\right] ...
- instead `\text{exp}` use declared math operators `\exp`
- `\\` after math environments are false, delete them

**edit:**

- for more space between paragraphs you should change `\parskip`, for example `\setlength\parskip{1\baselineskip}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength\parskip{1\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
The survival function is defined as the probability that an individual survives longer than t. It can be expressed as
    \begin{align*}
S(t)&=P(T>t)\\
&=1-P(T\leq t)\\
&=1-F(t)
    \end{align*}

The survival function of the Gompertz distribution is given by,
    \begin{equation}
S(t;\gamma;\lambda)=\exp\left[\frac{\lambda}{\gamma}(1-\mathrm{e}^{\gamma t})\right]
    \end{equation}
The hazard function of survival time is defined as the probability that an individual fails in a very short interval, t + $\Delta$t, given that the individual has survived to t.
    \begin{equation}
\frac{\lim_{\Delta t\to 0} P
    \left[
    \parbox{0.55\linewidth}{an individual fails in the interval $(t, t+\Delta t)$,\\
            given the individual has survived to $t$}
    \right]
    }{\Delta t}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

note (1): for given example the most of your preamble is unnecessary.

note (2): for starting new paragraph you need to insert empty line before it

[image]

is result what you looking for?

Comment: i want to have spaces after an equation like the spaces i did between paragraph. i use \\ between paragraph to get spacing

Comment: @yap never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph.

Comment: then how should i get a bigger space after a paragraph?

Comment: Set a non-zero value for `\parskip`.

Comment: @yap - To follow up on Bernard's comment: Executing the command `\setlength\parskip{1\baselineskip}` will insert the equivalent of 1 blank row between paragraphs. If that's too much whitespace for your taste, give `\setlength\parskip{0.5\baselineskip}` a try.

Comment: where should i add this command?

Comment: @yap, in document preamble.

Comment: If you want to insert additional vertical space only between some paragraphs and not all of them, simply use either `\smallskip` (~.25\baselineskip), `\medskip` (~.5\baselineskip), or `\bigskip` (\baselineskip), before or after a `\par` command (or a blank line), depending on what amount of spacing you want. Caution, these are elastic spaces, so they may vary according to the needs of the typeset page.